# CLI cannot generate pages in Ionic 2

Tags: cordova, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm having issues automatically generating pages in my new Ionic v2 project.

The following code:

```
ionic start appName --v2
```

...works perfectly to generate the project, then the following:

```
ionic platform add android
```

...works perfectly to add the missing platform, but when I input:

```
ionic g page pageName
```

Terminal gives me this error:

No ionic-angular package found, do you have Ionic installed? (CLI v2.0.0-beta.37)

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.3.1
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0-beta.37
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.20
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v6.6.0
Xcode version: Xcode 7.3.1 Build version 7D1014

...The most frustrating thing about this is that it was working just yesterday, so I'm really not sure what happened. Obviously Ionic is installed. I called it from the command line to create the project and add the missing platform.

EDIT: It looks like the project directory is missing the 'app' folder, but every other folder is present. I've made sure Node is updated and tried again, same thing happens.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to this issue: 
As you can see I was running Ionic v2.0.0-beta.37.
Drifty just released a new stable release candidate of Ionic 2 that has a different folder structure. For anyone experiencing this issue, the solution is to uninstall your current version of Ionic then install the most up to date version as per Ionic's documentation:

http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/getting-started/installation/

Once this is installed, close out of the command line completely then start it up again. You should find that page generation works.